# ¿Cómo eliminar la palabra "px" de un valor devuelto por un método?

Tags: javascript

Necesito sumar el margen superior e inferior de un elemento. Estos valores los obtengo usando jquery o javascript, el problema es que me retorna el valor con la palabra `"px"` al final, motivo por el que la suma falla.

Pongo el ejemplo:

```
var M = $( '#servicios' ).css( 'margin-top' ); //regresa 215px
alert(M + M) //regresa: 215px215px, pero deberia ser 430
```

La respuesta con jquery o javascript da igual, porque sé como mezclar ambas sintaxis sin que haya interferencia, aunque estoy trabajando con jquery.

Comment: `jquery` es una biblioteca escrita en/para `javascript`, no hace falta _mezclar_ ninguna sintaxis, pues el único lenguaje utilizado y por tanto la única sintaxis, es la de _javascript_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Va bien tu ejercicio, simplemente te hace falta por ejemplo pasar a la
variable `M` por `parseInt` para que el valor se tome como un número y
en este caso como número entero

Si miras en el ejemplo asigno a voluntad el valor que tendrá el `margin-top` para que el código de JQuery lo tome y lo sume

```js
var M = $( '#servicios' ).css( 'margin-top' );
console.log(parseInt(M) + parseInt(M))
```

```css
div{
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="servicios"></div>
```

Comment: Hola, edité tu respuesta para que pueda verse el resultado directamente dentro del navegador, puedes hacer clic en editar para ver cómo se hace. Mientras escribes la respuesta puedes utilizar el editor especial de _fragmento javascript/HTML/css_ para ejecutarla sin necesidad de publicar la respuesta cada vez.

Comment: te lo agradezco @jachguate :)

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió. Quería aceptar la sugerencia de edición que me mandó un usuario en este tema, pero la página dice que "no tengo reputación suficiente". Por suerte alcanzó al menos para darte mi voto.

Comment: @natan un gusto haberte ayudado, saludos